# How can I update a document from its source documents automatically in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, documents, automatic-update

Is there a way in Word 2007 to create a document using the text of other documents, and create a relationship between the main document and the source documents?

The purpose of this relationship would be to take text for every section of the main document from the source documents, and if you modified the source documents these changes would be updated in the main document automatically.

Comment: You can do this using VBA.

Comment: Do you mean to make a macro?

Comment: Macros use VBA as the control language, but they are limited in what they can do, since the macro recorder is limited. However, you can bypass the macro recorder altogether and create programs directly in VBA that can control Word (and the rest of Office). It's sometimes useful to record a macro to see the code produced, but much macro code is pretty inefficient. For example, the recorder will record every action that you do to create a table - insert 10 rows, nope, delete 5, wait, add 2 more for a total of 7 rows...

Comment: ... the resulting macro when played will insert 10, delete 5, insert 2, just as recorded. Or you can just write the VBA code to directly create the table with 7 rows. You can find more info at Microsoft's Word Developer Center... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905482.aspx